Youtube in a <video> element
I'm learning web development from scratch. I recently saw this on a website and don't know what's happening. I didn't know you could insert a Youtube video within a <video> tag using "src", I thought this was only possible to do with <iframe>. How does one do this?
youtube within 
I really have no idea how to do this. Thank you.

that YT blob URL is possibly a "temporary" direct video link which is why it's possible to use in a video tag!
